# fadeIn starts from the beginning after mouseleave (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for the solution for a navigation menu that I am working. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rameshrasaiyan/77r8ezsp/6/) where you can see the working code.

The fadeIn effect needs to happen only on the `nav-item` hover, but it is happening while mouseleave from the bottom, left or right side of the menu.

Comment: I would suggest using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `hover`. It might simplify your logic.

Comment: @Danny I tried with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, i got the same result.

Comment: @Danny No, that would be useless, `hover()` registers handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so no difference at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want is: when you move your mouse from a tab to another tab, you don't want the fade-out and in to happen.

In that case, it's because you're not keeping track of whether or not the menu is open. You should only do the fading if the menu was not open, otherwise simply hide and show with no fade.

Code:

```
var timer;
var isMenuOpen = false;
$('.nav-item').hover(
    function() {
        $('.subnav--main').hide();
        $('.promoted-content--main').hide();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if(isMenuOpen){
            $(this).find('ul').show();
        }
        else{
            isMenuOpen = true;
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn( 'slow' );
        }
    },
    function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.subnav--main').fadeOut( 'fast' );
            $('.promoted-content--main').fadeOut( 'fast' );
            isMenuOpen = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
);
```

And jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdafe3uw/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the menu to stay open and not have it fade out when hovering over different nav-items' the selector should be the nav--main

```
`var timer;
$('.nav--main').hover(function() {
    $('.subnav--main').hide();
    $('.promoted-content--main').hide();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).find('ul').fadeIn( 'slow' );
    },
    function() {
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.subnav--main').fadeOut( 'fast' );
        $('.promoted-content--main').fadeOut( 'fast' );
      }, 1000);
 });`
```